# Event ID 2284 and 2289 logged Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Our event log in Azure Web App has a bunch of Event [2289](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735142(v=ws.10).aspx) and [2284](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349265(v=ws.10).aspx) error entries by W3SVC-WP:

[image]

The messages are either something like this:

> 1
> 5
> \?\D:\home\LogFiles\W3SVC442144452\
> 02000780

Or like this:

> 1
> 5
> 50000780

I'm not sure where these come from but they seem to inhibit errors from logging correctly.

Comment: Azure Web App is a managed service. Diagnostics logging feature is also a managed feature provided by Azure Web App. There is not a easy way to find the root cause of this issue. Since your issue is related to the log, I suggest you disable and re-enable the diagnostics logging using Azure portal. Please check whether it will solve the issue?

Comment: @Amor thanks for your reply but this doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to having *Detailed error messages* and *Failed request tracing* (Diagnostic Logs) on during higher load. It is recommended to only enable these when the situation requires it.

[image: Diagnostic logs]